# gpu/nvidia isolation in dc/os

Tags: gpu, mesos, dcos

I installed DC/OS 1.9 on my own three VM, all node have no GPU resources, and the slave/slave-public node started up successfully. In one slave log it shows below:

```
Jun 15 04:43:28 localhost.localdomain mesos-agent[31752]: E0615 04:43:28.488627 31752 containerizer.cpp:335] Cannot create the Nvidia GPU isolator: NVML is not available
Jun 15 04:43:28 localhost.localdomain mesos-agent[31752]: 2017-06-15 04:43:28,494:31752(0x7f9291dd8700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@726: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.4.8
.....
Jun 15 04:43:28 localhost.localdomain mesos-agent[31752]: I0615 04:43:28.495215 31752 slave.cpp:211] Mesos agent started on (1)@192.168.3.72:5051
```

In my another test environment whose mesos version is 1.0.1, I start a mesos slave (the node also have no GPU resources) with "cgroups/devices,gpu/nvidia" isolation, but it failed to start. The logs show:

```
Jun 15 09:29:39 w-388965952-ClusterTest-sysadmin linker-start-agent.sh[25300]: Failed to create a containerizer: Could not create MesosContainerizer: Failed to create isolator 'gpu/nvidia': Cannot create the Nvidia GPU isolator: NVML is not available
Jun 15 09:29:39 w-388965952-ClusterTest-sysadmin systemd[1]: dcos-mesos-slave.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 15 09:29:39 w-388965952-ClusterTest-sysadmin systemd[1]: Unit dcos-mesos-slave.service entered failed state.
Jun 15 09:29:39 w-388965952-ClusterTest-sysadmin systemd[1]: dcos-mesos-slave.service failed.
```

I want to know: Does a node with no GPU resources can start mesos-salve with gpu/nvidia isolation? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior here for DC/OS is slightly different than in vanilla Mesos.

- With vanilla Mesos, the agent will refuse to start if you enable the `gpu/nvidia` isolator but NVML is not installed.
- With DC/OS, the agent will emit a warning message if NVML is not installed (the `gpu/nvidia` isolator is always enabled).

*Note:* the dependency is on the NVML libraries, not actual GPU resources. If NVML is installed but no GPUs are found on the box, then the agent won't fail to start with the `gpu/nvidia` isolator enabled.

Comment: This is where that difference comes from: https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos/commit/13783195d6ea8e34f528022cd13a5dba4bd32c62